# Calculando tempo médio

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql

No meu banco eu tenho uma tabela que possui os campos `entrada`, `saida`, os dois campos possuem o formato `D-MM-YYYY H:M:S`, gostaria de fazer um calculo médio.

Ex: O tempo medio de espera é de 30 min

Baseado em todos os resultados da minha tabela, é possivel? eu pensei em algumas formas de fazer isso, mas nao consegui nem chegar em uma solucao ou uma logica funcional.

Eu uso `Mysql`. `id | id_ent | entrada | saida | status`

Comment: Não é mais fácil fazer esse cálculo diretamente no banco de dados?

Comment: @Sorack pode ser tambem, mas nao sabia que era possivel fazer isso diretamente do banco

Comment: Coloca aí qual o seu banco e mais ou menos a estrutura da sua tabela que podemos dar uma resposta baseado nisso

Comment: @Sorack Atualizei

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adicionalmente você pode calcular a média diretamente na sua `query` que retorna os dados do banco da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT AVG(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(t.saida, t.entrada))) / 60 AS espera_media
  FROM tabela t
```

Comment: Uma duvida depois de um bom tempo kkk, que tipo meu campo deve ter? pois o retorno está ficando negativo.

Comment: @RafaelAugusto erro meu, a entrada deve ser depois da saída nos parâmetros

Comment: Agora sim, valeu :D

Answer (score 5):

Em Javascript (e na maioria das linguagens, na verdade), datas e horários são representados na memória como a quantidade de milissegundos desde uma data-hora arbitrária. Você pode ver esse número ao utilizar a função [getTime](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) do tipo Date, assim:

```
var agora = new Date();
agora.getTime();
```

Então, para saber quanto tempo um atendimento levou, você pode fazer o seguinte:

```
var horaEntrada = foo;
var horaSaida = bar;

var tempoAtendimentoEmMilissegundos = bar.getTime() - foo.getTime();
```

Apenas troque `foo`e `bar` pelos horários propriamente ditos de entrada e saída.

Se quiser converter o tempo de atendimento para outras unidades de medida, é fácil:

```
var tempoAtendimentoEmSegundos = tempoAtendimentoEmMilissegundos / 1000;
var tempoAtendimentoEmMinutos = tempoAtendimentoEmSegundos / 60;

// etc., etc.
```

Finalmente, para obter a média, basta fazer uma conta simples. Acumule todos os tempos em uma soma, e divida a soma pela quantidade de atendimentos.

```
var soma = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < tempos.length; i++) {
    soma += tempos[i];
}
var media = soma / tempos.length;
```

Comment: Vou testar e ja te dou um feedback ;)